# Type annotation of a subclass method that returns an instance of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a `MeasurementBase` abstract parent class that have the following functionality: (1) public `serialize()` & `deserialize()`

I would love to implement the common logic on the parent public methods and to define the private `_serialize()` &  `_deserialize()` abstract.

The base class implementation is as follows:

```
import json
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Dict, Generic, TypeVar


TMeasurement = TypeVar("TMeasurement")


class MeasurementBase(ABC, Generic[TMeasurement]):

    def serialize(self) -> str:
        properties: Dict[str, Any] = {}
        properties["measurement_name"] = self.__class__.__name__
        properties["value"] = self._serialize()
        return json.dumps(properties)

    @abstractmethod
    def _serialize(self) -> Any:
        pass  # pragma: no cover

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, json_str: str) -> TMeasurement:
        try:
            properties = json.loads(json_str)
            class_name = properties["measurement_name"]
            if cls.__name__ != class_name:
                raise KeyError()

            return cls._deserialize(properties["value"])
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError()

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def _deserialize(cls, obj: Any) -> TMeasurement:
        pass  # pragma: no cover
```

Then, I created a new subclass with internal `_val` state that implements the abstract methods:

```
class MeasurementBaseMock(MeasurementBase["MeasurementBaseMock"]):
    def __init__(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._val = val

    def _serialize(self) -> Any:
        return self._val

    @classmethod
    def _deserialize(cls, obj: int) -> "MeasurementBaseMock":
        return MeasurementBaseMock(obj)
```

Then, when testing the above:

```
properties = {"value": 324, "measurement_name": MeasurementBaseMock.__name__}
measurement = MeasurementBaseMock.deserialize(json.dumps(properties))
print(measurement._val)
```

I got the following error:

`error: "TMeasurement" has no attribute "_val"`

How do I annotate the `_deserialize` return type to support the typecker?

Things that I tried: 
- I tried using the `TMeasurement = TypeVar("TMeasurement", bound = "MeasurementBase")` - didnt work and had much more mypy error. 
- I moved all the state's initialization to parent class - this one did work, but I prefer not using such design. 
- I treid also using cls annotations but had the same error.

Note:
I'm using mypy

```
> mypy --version
mypy 0.660
```

Comment: This may be fixed in newer versions of mypy? At least I'm not able to repro your issue when using mypy 0.710. Also, you may be interested in [generic methods with a generic self](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) as a way of potentially eliminating the need to make your `MeasurementBase` class inherently generic.